# why software can't access my usb web cam on my rasberry pi 3?

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, camera, usb

please, I would like to know why my usb webcam does not work on my rasberry pi 3 model B+, when I enter the command "lsusb", I see that the webcam is detected, but when I launch "cheese", it shows me that no device is detected

the v4l2-ctl -V command display this:

```
Format Video Capture:
Width/Height : 640/360
Pixel Format : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
Field : None
Bytes per Line : 1280
Size Image : 460800
Colorspace : sRGB
Transfer Function : Rec. 709
YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
Quantization : Default (maps to Limited Range)
Flags :
```

I tried to lunch cheese in terminal with and without sudo:

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dsjn.png)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo cheese` ?

Comment: i tried to lunch with cheese with sudo, the response was : No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

Comment: Ok, are you running an X11 GUI/server somewhere? What happens if you run `xclock`, or `xterm` or `xeyes`?

Comment: the xeyes and xclock commands work well, but xterm command shows me command not found

Comment: Maybe try `xhost + ; sudo cheese`

Comment: after entering xhost +; the error has changed: (cheese:5436): cheese-WARNING **: 15:18:13.095: Impossible d’allouer la mémoire nécessaire.: gstv4l2src.c(658): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin28/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Buffer pool activation failed